# jdbc doesn't run what SQL Developer runs

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql

So I'm using jdbc in a Java application to query a couple of different databases. I have the user enter their credentials for each.

One of the databases is working fine, but for the other, I have two issues.

For one of the queries:

The select statement runs fine and returns a full row of 5 items from SQL developer (the SQL IDE from Oracle), but when executed from the Java application, only the second and third columns put data in my variables, the rest are empty strings. Here is the SELECT statement:

```
SELECT CD_DIST, CD_RQMT, TS_OPER_LAST_UPDTD, ID_OPER_LAST_UPDTD, ST_RQMT
    FROM TWMMILESTONERQMT
    WHERE CD_WR = '219033'
    and CD_RQMT = '555';
```

And here is the Java code:

```
        String wrNumber = ((Integer)(p.myWRNumber)).toString();
        String selectStatement =
        "SELECT CD_DIST, CD_RQMT, TS_OPER_LAST_UPDTD, ID_OPER_LAST_UPDTD, ST_RQMT " + 
            "FROM TWMMILESTONERQMT " + 
            "WHERE CD_WR = '" + wrNumber + "' " + 
            "and CD_RQMT = '555' ";
        System.out.println(selectStatement);

        PreparedStatement sel1 = stormsConn.prepareStatement(selectStatement);
        ResultSet res = sel1.executeQuery();
        while(res.next())
        {
            String district = res.getString("CD_DIST");
            String requirement = res.getString("CD_RQMT");
            String lastUpdatedTimestamp = res.getString("TS_OPER_LAST_UPDTD");
            String lastUpdatedPerson = res.getString("ID_OPER_LAST_UPDTD");
            String requirementState = res.getString("ST_RQMT");
            if(district != null)
            {
                p.myRequirementDistrict = district;
            }
            if(requirement != null)
            {
                p.myRequirementNumber = requirement;
            }
            if(lastUpdatedTimestamp != null)
            {
                p.myRequirementLastUpdatedTimestamp = lastUpdatedTimestamp;
            }
            if(lastUpdatedPerson != null)
            {
                p.myRequirementLastUpdatedPerson = lastUpdatedPerson;
            }
            if(requirementState != null)
            {
                p.myRequirementState = requirementState;
            }
        }

        res.close();
        sel1.close();
```

For the other query, it runs fine in SQL Developer again, but I get this Exception thrown when I run it in the Java application:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

For both queries I am using the same credentials as I am using in SQL developer, otherwise I would have suspected that it was a permissions issue. I've been knocking my brain against this for a few hours with no luck.

**Update (resolved):**

For the exception, I was using the wrong `Connection` to run my query, so I was looking for the Table in the wrong database. No wonder it wasn't found.

As for the mystery of the blank result columns, apparently `varchar2` type columns in the Oracle DB cannot use the `.getString(...)` function of the jdbc driver. Instead the `.getAsciiStream(..)` function must be used, and then that `InputStream` can be converted into a `String`. That *really* sucks that it doesn't warn you or anything that that datatype can't be returned that way. It should throw an exception, or be implemented in the jdbc driver, I think.

Thanks all for the help!

Comment: Are you sure, that the column data types are matching to string? You always call `res.getString()` but this maybe doesn't work for a e.g. a date. Additionally you can try to use the `getXXX()` variants with the column index as parameter instead of the column name.

Comment: I tried changing it to use `.getString(int columnIndex)`, but there is no change. I investigated the data types in the DB because of your comment, and interestingly, it seems that the ones that are other data types such as a `Date` or `Number` are the ones that *are* working, and the ones that are `varchar2` type are not working in the query I posted. I am quite mystified as to why this is happening, since the query seems to be executing without exceptions.

Comment: Success! You were on the right track with data types, thank you. It turns out that `varchar2` types have to use the `.getAsciiStream(...)` function instead of `.getString(...)`! So then you get an `InputStream` which can be converted to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are same users are these programs running from different machines?is there any ip block ?
write a simple select query in java side for the same table without the parameters
"SELECT CD_DIST from TWMMILESTONERQMT" see if this works

Comment: I tried `SELECT CD_DIST from TWMMILESTONERQMT WHERE 1 = 1`
which was a good idea, but each row is still just an empty string in the `String district` variable.

Everything is being run on the same desktop, no VMs or remote conncetions.

Comment: so this time you did not get java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist ?

Comment: try executing "SELECT CD_DIST from TWMMILESTONERQMT where CD_DIST is not null limit 5"

Comment: On the TWMMILESTONERQMT table I never get that exception, it just gives me empty strings for the first, fourth, and fifth columns.

A different query, against the TWMADDRESS joined to TWMWR, is the one that gives the exception.

Comment: Tried the `not null` statement, same results unfortunately.

Comment: so that means TWMWR table has issues try doing same select * from  TWMWR do you get the ORA-00942 ?

Comment: Ok, stupidly enough I got rid of the exceptions. I was using the connection for the other db for that query. *facepalm*

However, now it's behavior is similar to the first query, giving mostly blank strings, with a few `null`s.